# How can I clean up this OpenLayers code by correctly doing a transform or projection, for an array of features?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, coordinate-system

I have some features I've created via some Kml data.

Now, to display these features on a Google Map, I need to project them from *'EPSG:4326'* to *'EPSG:3857'*. This works great.

Now, i need to convert this to WKT *4326*. When I do that, i re-transform the features but the google map doesn't display them any more because the features are in the wrong projection.

Can anyone suggest a way to clean up my code so I can keep the features in 4326 format, but when I need to display these features on my Layer, it's smart enough to transform it into 3857.

Here's [my full javascript code](https://github.com/PureKrome/GeospatialConversions/blob/master/Code/Kml2Wkt.Web.Application/Scripts/GeoSpatial.js) ... but here's the important bits in there...

```
// Converts some Kml string data into an array of Features.
function convertKmlToFeatures(kml) {
    var kmlFormat = new OpenLayers.Format.KML();
    var features = kmlFormat.read(kml);
    for (var i = 0, l = features.length; i < l; i++) {
        features[i].geometry.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
    }
    return features;
}

.....
// Display features. 
// NOTE: (This will be as 3857 .. but i wish i can leave this as 4326 and
//        just transform on the fly, here).
map.layers[1].addFeatures(features);


.....
// Finally Output the features as WKT. This needs to be as 4326.
// Right now, it's still as 3857.
var wktFormat = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();
return wktFormat.write(features);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should extend your Layer with custom protocol option.

```
var options_proj = {
    'internalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
    'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
   };

new OpenLayers.Format.WKT({
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP(
        { url: "kml path", 
          format: new OpenLayers.Format.WKT(options_proj)})
    //... other options
});
```

Therefore,when layer is loaded,it converts kml objects directly to features between projections you specified without writing extra conversion code.

Comment: Worked! Instead of having to grab the data via HTTP, I just did this: `var wktFormat = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT(options);` and it did it :) :) :)